# How to enable YouTube which is banned on a system

Tags: youtube, hosts

I have YouTube banned in my system. How can I enable it?

I tried to lookup for it in `/etc/hosts.deny` file but couldn't locate it.

Looking for an Ubuntu specific solution, how to disable/enable it?
does modifying `hosts.deny` helps or not?

Comment: You want help to violate an office policy? Or what do you mean by "banned in my system"?

Comment: What happens when you try to access YouTube?

Comment: former one @vasa.. :P

Comment: it says:-
Access to the requested web page has been blocked by NexTag internet usage protection policy. ACCESS BLOCKED

Comment: @vasa1 This is a legitimate question, *even* if you consider breaking rules universally illegitimate. 2 examples: An office might use automated software to block access to YouTube after discovering (or otherwise coming to believe) that most YouTube access violated existing policies (e.g., about work-relateness). Circumventing the automated policy doesn't entail breaking the rule it's designed to enforce. Or the rule may be for YouTube use during "company time" only. With that said, under many circumstances (especially where practical) it's advisable to consult/inform a supervisor or IT first.

Comment: If you notice, I have **not** questioned the legitimacy of the question. "Banned in my system" was confusing to me. I asked for a clarification and suggested a possibility. OP clarified that my suggestion appropriately described the situation. IANAL, so I won't go into *violate* versus *circumvent* :)

Comment: @vasa1, your debate is with Eliah, i never opposed you, please do not downvote the question because of him

Comment: Don't worry about upvotes and downvotes. Focus on asking good, clear questions and providing the best answers you can.

Comment: that is what i am doing, but too many downvotes will block me from asking questions. Shouldn't i worry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used `https` instead of `http` and I was able to open the youtube :)

Comment: i was able to open the youtube videos using `https` but when i executed the command `wget https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw` in Terminal it gave the following response:- `--2013-03-04 13:09:28--  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw
Resolving www.youtube.com (www.youtube.com)... 74.125.236.167, 74.125.236.160, 74.125.236.164, ...
Connecting to www.youtube.com (www.youtube.com)|74.125.236.167|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.`

Comment: Can i wget YouTube videos or not at all??
                 How can I download the YouTube videos in this scenario?

Comment: I recommend posting a separate question to ask how to download YouTube videos via HTTPS.

Comment: ok.. i was afraid of downvoting. That's why i didn't ask a separate question

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure that this is the right place to ask that question, since it's got nothing to do with Ubuntu (or any specific OS for that matter), BUT... Since it's already there, I might as well answer you :)

A note first: Before anyone thinks that it is 'not right' to try to circumvent a rule like this, there can actually exist a number of situations when there is no other way to access somethings that are otherwise completely legal and allowed and there's nothing wrong in doing so or trying to do so. I myself have had an awful opportunity to live in a place where so many convenient websites are blocked on a country level (I'm talking about Skype and Flickr and things like that, completely harmless). Also, rational people should not be approving any kind of restrictions, and grown-ups need to be responsible for their own actions.

Depending on the method used to block the content, there might be one or more methods (or none :) ) that you can use. The first thing that I'd suggest is trying to use a proxy server. You can do it in several ways. The best place to start would be [Hide My Ass](http://hidemyass.com/). There you can:

- Use a web proxy: Just type an address in the Web Proxy field on the Hide My Ass homepage;
- Find the [List of ip:port proxy addresses](http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/) that you can use in your browser. If you don't know how to use these addresses, please leave a comment here;

You can also find many useful instructions on that website.

A second solution is to use [Tor project and its Vidalia tool](https://www.torproject.org/projects/vidalia.html.en). Basically, it's a shared connection tool. You have several options there too.

- One, download and install [Vidalia Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en). It includes the proxy
  solution and a browser already set up to work with Tor network.
- Or you can install Vidalia tool separately (I believe it's available
  from Ubuntu Software Centre) and then set up your browser to use a
  proxy server on your localhost address.

There is some great documentation on Vidalia's website, but if you're having trouble with it, feel free to leave a comment here.

Another possible solution that I just remembered might help you is to download and install [Opera desktop browser](http://www.opera.com/browser/). When you open Opera, enable its [Opera Turbo feature](http://www.opera.com/browser/turbo/). Opera Turbo is a traffic compression tool by Opera, but by nature it uses Opera's proxy servers. That might be handy.

Finally, also in Opera, you have a feature to browse internet in a 'Private tab'. I'm really not sure if that will help, but it's worth mentioning. I also have no idea if any other browser has this feature. To enable private browsing in Opera, click on Opera button > Tabs and Windows > New private tab, and browse away :)

Comment: it says video not found for all of the videos in youtube

Comment: for your 2nd comment, i searched for india>> http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-225457

and then navigated to first result, http://111.125.139.199/ it is asking for admin login

Comment: tried accessing yahoomail using this hidemyass and it said "ebable javascript in your browser" while it was already enabled

Comment: It is actually quite cumbersome to find a long-term working ip:port proxy server. But if you keep trying, you will succeed eventually. Indian proxies are not the best idea. Try using Russian ones, I've had some luck with them. Also, while searching, include only fast speed fast connection, high and high+ka anonymity, and sort results by date tested. That can help you a bit. I'm not sure why web proxy isn't working on hidemyass.com but as I mentioned, that can be only your start. There are tons of them around the net. I'm also gonna include in my answer another solution.

Comment: Make some friends in your IT department. They will eventually give you access to the mighty you-can-do-anything-proxy :-)

Comment: Turkish proxies aren't bad, either.

Comment: is there any proxyless solution??

Comment: Theoretically, there might be, but it depends on the actual content blocking method that is used. In practice, proxy turns out to be the only relatively practical solution.